# Send Email in spring

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc

I read all related topics, but in all of them there was this line:

`mailSender.send(message);`

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/

But there is no `send()` at all, i see `mailSender.sendMail()` method with this arguments:

```
String s, String[] string,String[] string1,String[] string2,String s1,String s2
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Mail {

private MailSender mailSender;

public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
}

public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String msg) {

    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    String[] array = new String[];
    array[0]="from@gmail.com";
    array[1]="to@gmail.com";
    array[2]="subject";
    array[3]="text";

    message.setFrom(from);
    message.setTo(to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(msg);
    mailSender.sendMail(); // what should be here?

}
}
```

What is this arguments?

Comment: See docs for MailSender: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailSender.html.  Are you sure you're importing the right MailSender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use full path to mail sender

```
private  org.springframework.mail.MailSender  mailSender;
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface `org.springframework.mail.MailSender` provides two methods:

- `void send(SimpleMailMessage simpleMessage) throws MailException;`
- `void send(SimpleMailMessage[] simpleMessages) throws MailException;`

See

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailSender.html
- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context-support/4.1.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.java#JavaMailSender

So you are wrong (*"...But there is no send() at all..."*) and the tutorials are right!

Double check that your `MailSender` is the one from `org.springframework.mail`